# How to split value with asterisk and get first digit using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, split

I just need to split below value with dynamic like " *-+/., " values.
after that i need to get only first character

Input =

09.29.96.66

72*77*27*22

Output =

09 - 0

29 - 2

96 - 9

66 - 6

second line start

72 - 7

77 - 7

27 - 2

22 - 2

something like that.

Comment: Please show the actual code that isn't working, so we can see where you need help.

Comment: So are the numbers after the dash, just the first digit of each number?

Comment: @juharr - suppose my number is 32+34, so my output is 32 and 34 need to do split, then fetch first digit.

Comment: Do you have to use regex?  Seems like you could just do `string.Split` and pass in the list of characters to split on.

Comment: string[] result = Regex.Split("09.29,96.66", @"[.]|[,]|[+]|[-]").Select(x => $"{x} - {x.First()});

Comment: regex findall try  `(?:(?<=[-*/.,])|^|\s)\d+(?=[-*/.,]|\s|$)` no split https://regex101.com/r/523x4w/1

Comment: @user3401335 that's good but after split i need only first digit of each.

Comment: @BhaveshThummar look at this https://rextester.com/MFCK97580.
I found that is what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to get the above output. You can simply do the following:

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            "09.29.96.66"
                .Split(new char[] { '.','*','+','-','*','/'})
                .Select(s=>$"{s} - {s.FirstOrDefault()}"))
```